# NSPredicate to exclude slow motion videos from PHFetchResults

Tags: ios, objective-c, photosframework, phfetchoptions

```
NSString *predicateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"mediaSubtype = %zd", PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicateFormat];

    PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
    fetchOptions.predicate = predicate;

    PHFetchResult *userAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumVideos options:fetchOptions];
```

This is my code to fetch videos which excludes slow motion videos. But I'm getting following error.This doesn't work even if I do like this,

```
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mediaSubtype & %d) == 0", PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate];
```

Somebody please help. Thanks in advance.

```
Unsupported predicate in fetch options: mediaSubtype == 131072
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mediaSubtype != %d)", PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate];
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4

```
let assetFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
assetFetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT ((mediaSubtype & %d) != 0)", PHAssetMediaSubtype.videoHighFrameRate.rawValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

To exclude slow motion videos, the only predicate that worked for me is this:

```
PHFetchOptions *options = [PHFetchOptions new];
// Disable slow motion videos
options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT ((mediaSubtype & %d) != 0)", PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate];
```